# How i can do a case-insensitive sort inside my content search web part

Tags: 2013, development, search, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I am working on a content search web part, which show a list of sub-sites under the current site collection.
now i want to Sort the sub-sites inside the webpart using their site description field. and to do so i map the `Refinablestring01` managed property with the `ows_SiteDescription` crawl property as follow:-

[image]

then inside my content search web part i chose to sort the results using the `refinablestring01` managed property as follow:-

[image]

now the problem is that the sort i am receiving is case sensitive. as if i have a site with the following description "**This site was created upon manager request**" will be shown before a site with the following description "**abc**". so if the site start with an upper case it will always be shown before lower case. so is there a way to force a case-insensitve sort inside my content search webpart ? now if i change the first site description to start with a lower case as follow "**this site was created upon manager request**" then this site will be shown after "**abc**"..
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SharePoint Search, it will sort Character with "A-Z" then "a-z", it is by design, because Lower Case character will have a larger ASCII value compare with Upper Case character.  SharePoint Search will sort based on ASCII value.

[Case insensitive sorting in SharePoint](http://www.techmikael.com/2015/08/how-to-do-case-insensitive-sorting-in.html)

A workaround is that create a new field with all  character converted to Lower Case character and then sort by the new field instead.

Comment: but i can not create a new field with all characters converted to Lower Case characters, as i am sorting sites not list items.. and for the site they come with built-in fields such as title, description, logo... so you mean there is not a way to fix the sort issue..

Comment: yes, it is by design to sort with ASCII value.